# Are limits.conf values applied on a per-process basis?

Tags: linux, files, limit

I'm tuning the `nofile` value in `/etc/security/limits.conf` for my oracle user and I have a question about its behavior: does `nofile` limit the total number of files the user can have open for *all* of its processes or does it limit the total number of files the user can have open for *each* of its processes?

Specifically, for the following usage:

```
oracle                  hard    nofile                  65536
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Most of the values¹ in `limits.conf` are limits that can be set with the `ulimit` shell command or the [`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) system call. They are properties of a process. The limits apply independently for each process. In particular, each process can have up to `nofile` open files. There is no limit to the number of open files cumulated by the processes of a user.

The `nproc` limit is a bit of a special case, in that it does sum over all the processes of a user. Nonetheless, it still applies per-process: when a process calls `fork` to create a new process, the call is denied if the number of processes belonging to the process's euid is would be larger than the process's `RLIMIT_NPROC` value.

The [`limits.conf` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html) explains that the limits apply to a session. This means that all the processes in a session will all have these same limits (unless changed by one of these processes). It doesn't mean that any sum is done over the processes in a session (that's not even something that the operating system tracks — there is a notion of session, but it's finer-grained than that, for example each X11 application tends to end up in its own session). The way it works is that the login process sets itself some limits, and they are inherited by all child processes.

¹  <sub>The exceptions are `maxlogins`, `maxsyslogins` and `chroot`, which are applied as part of the login process to deny or influence login.</sub>

Comment: Conversely, does that mean different sessions can have different sets of limits?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, for example if `limit.conf` changed between the times the sessions were open, or if different limits (they'd have to be smaller  except for root) are set in `.profile`.

Comment: hi @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' so your answer explains well that `nproc` has total limit per Shell session, not a process. Is there an equivalent of `sudo prlimit --pid 2146 --nproc=8096:1048576` per session and not per process to avoid downtime?

Comment: @laimison Not with `prlimit`: that sets process limits. You can use cgroups to set some limits that apply to a group of processes as a whole.

Comment: I'm having nodes that reached 4096 default threads/processes limit for k8s user. So thinking whether it's possible to uplift this without downtime on loads of production nodes. When the issue kicks in, I can see around 4000+ threads using `ps -u k8s -L | wc -l` on that node. Now my understanding is that user should be logged out and logged in to make this `nproc` setting effective. That means shutdown all services for us. Interested if there is a quick way available.

Comment: @laimison If you iterate over all running processes and run `prlimit --pid $pid` on each, you can effectively change the limit for an active session. Note that you may have to do it a few times in case some processes are forked while you're iterating.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it worked, I looped this through all processes. I tried to fill up user with processes & threads and solve this issue without downtime. It's pretty weird, but I had to do `sed -i 's/.*k8s.*/k8s soft nproc 8192/g' /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf` as well on my Centos to allow me to shell to k8s user without `/bin/bash: Resource temporarily unavailable` error. I could be wrong, but I guess that 20-nproc.conf is somehow checked when opening new shell/new process.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' do you know how this scenario will work to proof nproc behaviour. An example: PID10 root created two processes in parallel using su user1: PID100 for user1 and PID200 for user1. They came from PID10. PID10 is set to 4096. PID100 and PID200 both have nproc at 8192. Will root process limit everything to 4096? PID10 is root owned process, but it has limit of 4096 (not sure how it was set, but /proc/10/limits confirms that).

Comment: @laimison The limit is enforced when a process calls `fork`. The liimt that applies is whatever is set at the time for the process calling `fork`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I bit more expertise needed to summarise this. So how it calculates the sum for a user then as you stated in original answer? Let's say I'm root and started two separate processes for user1 in parallel. As I'm using root, I'm unlimited, but I specified manually nproc of 4096 for first process and 8192 for another process. Am I right that value of `RLIMIT_NPROC` is just default value (when I don't specify). So in the end it means that user1 can reach 4096+8192=12288 count if both processes are consuming 100% of processes/threads?

Comment: @laimison No. Suppose that a user has only two processes A and B, with `RLIMIT_NPROC` set to 2 in A and to 3 in B. Then B can fork one more process, but A cannot.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' cool, that explains it. I believe, if I manually change RLIMIT_NPROC to 2 of parent PID or any grandparent PID above A & B in the processes tree, then B will lose an opportunity for additional process based on your example?

Comment: @laimison If you set the limit to 2 in B's parent and don't change it in B after forking, then B's limit will be 2. If you set the limit to 2 in B's parent but you raise the limit in B, or if you set the limit to 3 in B's parent before forking B and set it to 2 after forking B, B will have the limit set to 3. The only limit that matters is the one in the process that calls fork(), not the limit in that process's parent or in any other process.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' fair enough. Now I see that I had a wrong understanding  in every way that I've tried to brainstorm. Especially was wrong that some sum exists in the hierarchy. To get back to the big picture, can we simplify everything into this 1) process is limited by individual nproc value (when fork() called, before this process creation or prlimit used after the fact) 2) second limit is nproc limit for number of processes belonging to the process's euid. Can we think that there are two limitations or that is oversimplified?