# What level is the value `ulimit -n`mean? user level or process level?

Tags: linux, files, process, ulimit

I want to increase the `ulimit -n` value,so I add

```
*       soft  nofile  20000
*       hard  nofile  20000
```

in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, but there is a question confuse me all the time.
**what level is the value `ulimit -n` mean? user level or process level?**
Specifically speaking, if the value of `ulimit -n` is 512, and user `testUser` hava 3 process, does it means `testUser` can have the total file descriptors for 512 sum up for all his 3 process, or does it means each of `testUser's` process can have 512 file descriptors and thus `testUser` can hava a total file descriptors amount of `512*3`?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour changes depend on if its a systemd service or not which i am not capable of pointing differences.

/etc/security/limits.conf file sets the limits for root user, if you would like to increase a user's limits, you should edit /etc/security/limits.d/testUser.conf file.

Comment: And what is the level of `ulimit -n` control ? user or process?thanks

Comment: -n   The maximum number of open file descriptors.

file descriptor: In Unix and related computer operating systems, a file descriptor (FD, less frequently fildes) is an abstract indicator (handle) used to access a file or other input/output resource, such as a pipe or network socket.

Comment: And as the example I mention in the question, if `testUser` have 3 process, what is the max `file descriptor` amount can `testUser` get? 512 or 512*3?

Comment: [Are limits.conf values applied on a per-process basis?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55319/are-limits-conf-values-applied-on-a-per-process-basis),this answer seems have the opposite point of view

Comment: Man page  https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf  says
 The pam_limits.so module applies ulimit limits, nice priority and number of simultaneous login sessions limit to user login sessions.

Comment: I will make a test in my linux to confirm the answer, thanks again.

Comment: I will make a test in my linux to confirm the answer, thanks again.